# Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa..HibernateJpaConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have changed my springboot version from 2.5.0 to 2.6.2 and when I run my backend I am getting the following error:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:862) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:850) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:837) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:778) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
```

Comment: Does that stack trace come with a `Caused by`? There's a good chance the actual error is on the `Caused by` part.

Comment: Produce full stacktrace in your question

Comment: Paste your pom.xm or gradle - What do you have declared for hibernate

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have incompatible version of hibernate-core on the classpath. you can try to update pom.xml or build.gradle to use compatible version. Use spring boot's dependency management rather than specifying the version yourself.
You can delete the existing jar and then rebuild your application.